# How to handle the finishing of changing the value in the grid cell in GXT2

Tags: java, grid, gxt

I have an app with GXT. In this app there is a grid in which I need to edit values in cells. I create cells in this way:

```
column = new ColumnConfig();
fieldEditor = new CellEditor(new TextField<String>());
column.setEditor(fieldEditor);
column.setId("value");
column.setHeader("Value");
column.setWidth(650);
configs.add(column);
```

As you see I use `TextField` as an editor. so, after I change the value I can press Enter or click in any other place of the window. how to handle this. I tried to handle `ButtonPress` event and MouseClick event, but this drops an exception or don't do anything.

**UPD:** NOw I'm trying to implement this in the following way:

```
valueEditor = new TextField<String>();
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener(){
    @Override
    public void componentKeyUp(ComponentEvent event){
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER){
        if (valueEditor.getValue() != null && !("").equals(valueEditor.getValue())){
           Window.alert("Enter Button Pressed");
           PropertyItem item;
           item = new PropertyItem(grid.getStore().getAt(rowNumber).getName(),                 
                grid.getStore().getAt(rowNumber).getType(), valueEditor.getValue(),    
                grid.getStore().getAt(rowNumber).isAccepted());
           store.update(item);
           store.commitChanges();
           saveProperties(store, customerId, toRemove);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        valueEditor.addKeyListener(keyListener);
```

and what is the problem: it doesn't handle the Enter press in the end of editing, but only handle it after the editing deactivated.

Comment: u can add MouseHandler to that TextField before setting?

Comment: Do you want something like this ? http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#editablegrid

Comment: not actually this. I'd like it to save right after I press Enter or click wherever in the window

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle **enter event** on TextField than you can used following code

```
TextField<String> field = new TextField<String>();
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener(){
    @Override
    public void componentKeyUp(ComponentEvent event) {
        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
};
field.addKeyListener(keyListener);

column = new ColumnConfig();
fieldEditor = new CellEditor(field);
column.setEditor(fieldEditor);
column.setId("value");
column.setHeader("Value");
column.setWidth(650);
configs.add(column);
```

if it's not help to you than you can used focus lost event.
hope it will help you.

Comment: It doesn't handle event when the button pressed in the end of editing. only after the cell with text field deactivated it handles the event of pressing button